# PHP: Convert shorthand Hex Colors to Regular

Tags: php, colors, hex

I'm trying to make a function that will take short hand hex color to the long hex color.

For example if someone submits "f60" it will convert to "ff6600". I understand I need to repeat each number as itself, but what is the most efficient way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I think in this case, efficiency is the least problem ... Just go with the simplest solution and you're fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work. However, you'll want to make sure the strings aren't prepended with a `#` due to the exact `strlen` comparison.

```
// Done backwards to avoid destructive overwriting
// Example: f60 -> ff6600
if (strlen($color) == 3) {
    $color[5] = $color[2]; // f60##0
    $color[4] = $color[2]; // f60#00
    $color[3] = $color[1]; // f60600
    $color[2] = $color[1]; // f66600
    $color[1] = $color[0]; // ff6600
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't know you could grab a character of a string with $variable[lenght]; I've learned a lot from this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`$fullColor =  $color[0].$color[0].$color[1].$color[1].$color[2].$color[2];`

You can access characters of a string as an array.

Answer (score 1):

this question cannot miss the good old regexes :D

```
 $color = preg_replace('/#([\da-f])([\da-f])([\da-f])/i', '#\1\1\2\2\3\3', $color);
```

not the best solution though …

Comment: This is hardly efficient in processing or legibility. I say avoid regexes when a simpler solution will suffice :P

Comment: i didn't say that ;) it's just provided so all regex-users are happy

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but an alternative
with these you can duplicate every kind of string with every length not only 3 as Hex colors

```
   <?php
     $double='';
     for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
            $double.=$str[$i].$str[$i];
     }
   ?>
```

or

```
<?php
 $str="FCD";
 $split=str_split($str);
 $str='';
 foreach($split as $char) $str.=$char.$char;
 echo $str;
?>
```

You could also use regex or other...

Comment: Certainly not the most efficient, because of the str_split call and the foreach loop. But that will work too...